# Отбивается ли пробелами косая черта в тексте?

Tags: пробелы, косая-черта

Был такой вопрос:

> Конфликт между трудовым и административным аспектом/аспектами...

Нужно ли в этом тексте и ему подобных отбивать косую черту пробелами?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

§ 114. Сфера применения **знака / (косая черта)** — научная и деловая речь. Он употребляется в следующих функциях.

1. В функции, близкой к союзам и и или, как знак альтерна­тивности понятий или обозначения единого сложного поня­тия, например:
   категория **одушевлённости/неодушевлённости**, про­блема **слитных/раздельных** написаний (в лингвистических тек­стах); Погребения датируются **новым/новейшим** временем (из археологической статьи); обязательство **покупки/продажи** цен­ных бумаг по объявленным ценам; Развивающий тренажёр «прыгунки» регулируется на **размер/вес** малыша (из газет).
2. Для обозначения отношения каких-либо величин, пара­метров (в том числе в математическом смысле), например:
   По па­раметрам — **цена/качество**, удобство в работе, простота в об­ращении — модель заняла лидирующее положение в своём классе множительной техники; Компьютер занял 4-е место по количеству набранных баллов и 2-е по отношению **баллы/цена**; Курс **доллар/евро** опустился до минимального значения за последние две недели; Новый ризограф с разрешающей способностью 600 **то­чек/дюйм** (из газет).
   В той же функции употребляется косая черта в сокращен­ных обозначениях составных единиц измерения, напр.: ц/га (центнер на гектар), об/мин (оборот в минуту).

[Полный академический справочник](http://bioraf.ru/pravila-russkoj-orfografii-i-punktuacii-polnij-akademicheskij.html?page=11)

Из самой статьи, в которой употреблена косая черта, видно, что **знак /** пробелами не отбивается.

И вот ещё, как мне кажется, весомое мнение.

*Надо или не надо ставить пробелы при употреблении слешки?*
**Пробел не нужен**
1) при написании сокращений (км/ч; ж/д);
2) если слеш употреблен в числах вместо тире (2011/2012);
**3)** если слеш разделяет **одиночные слова** (**приход/расход;  и/или**).

Внимание: НО! Если слеш стоит между словосочетаниями (или словом и словосочетанием) пробелы нужно ставить ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО!
Иначе читаем, что написано: 
У ребенка есть мама/приходящий папа. Получилась несуразица: мама/приходящий. 
ПРАВИЛЬНО: У ребенка есть мама / приходящий папа.

[Пробелы и косая черта (слеш)](http://esmira.net/uroki/tretij-urok.html)