# Оформление интервала дат

Tags: даты, косая-черта

Как правильно оформить интервал дат в разных летосчислениях: 555/1160–630/1233 или 555–630/1160–1233.     Если последний вариант, то не надо ли добавить пробелы вокруг слэша?

Comment: Может, "555–630 (1160–1233)"?

Comment: Обычно используют слэш.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Пробел не нужен:
   а) при написании сокращений (км/ч, ж/д, об/мин);
   б) при употреблении в числах вместо тире (2011/2012);
   в) при разделении одиночных слов (приход/расход, и/или, слитно/раздельно).

[Пробелы и косая черта (слеш)](http://esmira.net/uroki/tretij-urok.html)

2. Принципы летосчисления Вы не называете, но если предполагается, что длина календарного года одинакова, то и разница (количество лет) должна быть одинаковой. У Вас же в одном случае период составляет 75 лет, а в другом — 73 года.

[Летоисчисление](http://goodcoins.su/calendar.htm)

3. Пример, как я понимаю, абстрактный, поэтому многое (как в оформлении, так и в восприятии текста) зависит от принятых обозначений. Если уж обязательно нужно использовать слеш, то я вижу такие возможные варианты:

**555/1160 — 630/1235** [тире отбивается пробелами, слеш — нет];

**555 (1160) / 630 (1235)** [слеш и скобки отбиваются пробелами];

**555 [1160] / 630 [1235]** (слеш и скобки отбиваются пробелами);

**555–630 / 1160–1235** [слеш отбивается пробелами].

P. S. Обычно все-таки при записи "сложных", "многофункциональных" дат используют тире (для лучшего восприятия и во избежание двусмысленности).
Пётр I Алексеевич (30 мая [9 июня] 1672 года — 28 января [8 февраля] 1725 года);
Александр Македонский (предположительно 20/23 июля или 6/10 октября 356 года до н. э. — 10/13 июня 323 года до н. э.).

Comment: Пример, как раз, реальный (просто не хотел перегружать вопрос контекстом); летоисчисления - мусульманский календарь и григорианский (поэтому разница в интервалах не совпадает). Пока писал свой длинный комментарий, нашёл ваш же ответ на свой вопрос https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447260/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B И читается лучше, по-моему, ваш последний вариант.

Comment: Извиняюсь, что "заставляю" других выполнять свою работу. Спасибо!